# ArrayLiteralConvertible: Just a normal protocol?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

Trying to understand and appreciate how ArrayLiteralConvertible works...

```
struct Struct<T>: ArrayLiteralConvertible {

    init(arrayLiteral elements: T...) {
        for element in elements {
            print(element)
        }
    }
}

let str: Struct<Int> = [1,2,3]
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Now I am trying to do the same thing but this time with my own version of ArrayLiteralConvertible:

```
protocol MyALC {
    typealias Element
    init(arrLit elements: Self.Element...)
}

struct NewStruct<T>: MyALC {

    init(arrLit elements: T...) {
        for element in elements {
            print(element)
        }
    }
}

let newStr: NewStruct<Int> = [1,2,3]
```

However it does not work!

```
error: cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to specified type 'NewStruct'
let newStr: NewStruct = [1,2,3]
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a special handling for ArrayLiteralConvertible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, literals are a purely compile-time artifact. They can be used to produce an object initialized from that literal, but once the compilation phase is over, nobody knows that something was a literal.

This suggests that any support for the protocols below needs to be built into the compiler itself:

- `ArrayLiteralConvertible`
- `BooleanLiteralConvertible`
- `DictionaryLiteralConvertible`
- `ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralConvertible`
- `FloatLiteralConvertible`
- `NilLiteralConvertible`
- `IntegerLiteralConvertible`
- `StringLiteralConvertible`
- `StringInterpolationConvertible`
- `UnicodeScalarLiteralConvertible`

The compiler would not take your own protocol as a replacement of any of the above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer dasblinkenlight. However there are multiple aspects in your answer - some of which I would like to discuss: 1. Understood and agreed on your remarks regarding literals in general. 2. Also understood that like literals need compiler support, these protocol literals will also need the same. 3. What is difficult to digest (about Swift - not your answer) is that Swift will give specialized treatment to certain protocols. This appears "dishonest" from the perspective of a language. It would have been much better to openly classify these with a special construct.

Comment: @adev The approach when compiler support is added for specific classes of the standard library is commonplace these days. I know of situations when this happens in Java, C#, Objective-C, and Swift. By the way, there are many other places where Swift does it, too: for example, the compiler has baked-in support for `Optional<T>`, and also for things that you can put inside `if let something = ... {}` construct.

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight. I guess one just has to *know* these things when they happen. Esp wrt classes etc.